# Discrepancy between Java and database ordering

Tags: java, sorting, sql-order-by

I recently came across this problem.
I did some `select name from table order by name`. 
I got a response in this order : `a`, `A`, `b`, ..
When I called `Collections.binarySearch(A)` it did not get anything. 
But if I did `Collections.sort()` before search it worked fine.
To get to the issue I printed after `Collections.sort()` 
I got this result `A`, `a`, `b`, .. which is different from the result from database.
Why is this discrepancy in Java over data base?

Comment: Case sensitivity, apparently.

Comment: You wrote about the database:"I got a response in this order : `a, A, b`", and Java: " I got this result `a, A, b`". Am I missing something or it's the same order your report?